# Ionic background geolocation issue not working in background mode

Tags: ionic-framework

I am working on an IONIC Application which is showing service provider active location on google map with destination as user (lat,lon) and source as service provider active location (lat,lon).

Once service provider presses a button we are taking his location with "ionic cordova plugin add @mauron85/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation" plugin to take service provider location after 30 seconds.

It works when APP is in foreground, but it fails when app is being in-active or in back order.

I also used "ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-background-mode" to enable the background process if it is required. But still the issue is persists.

I am not able to take service provider location if APP is in background.

Code i placed in constructor as below:

```
this.backgroundGeolocation.configure(this.config).then(() => 
    {
      this.backgroundGeolocation.on(BackgroundGeolocationEvents.location).subscribe((location: BackgroundGeolocationResponse) => 
      {
          this.latitude = String(location.latitude);
          this.longitude = String(location.longitude);
          this.saveCordinates();
      });
    });
```

after every 30 seconds i use
this.backgroundGeolocation.start();

which initialise fills this.latitude, this.longitude and then i am saving them with this.saveCordinates(); function

Answer (score 0):

I also tried using that plugin and failed. After many hours of debugging I gave up and used another plugin.

I recommend using [this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@capacitor-community/background-geolocation) if you use Capacitor. It works perfectly on Android and iOS. For Cordova I heard [this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-background-geolocation-lt) is good, but I did not use it, so I am not sure.